# node.js: Accessing local variables from another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript, node-modules

### My Problem

I'm writing a `node` module called `a`, which `require()`s a module `b` (written by a stranger). Unfortunately, `a` doesn't only need to access the public members - it also needs to access local variables declared in the scope of the module.

```
// a
var b = require('b');

console.log(b.public);
console.log(b.private); // undefined


// b
var c = require('c');
var stdin = process.stdin;

exports.public = true;
var private = true;
```

### My Solution

```
// a
var b = require('b');
var srcPath = require.resolve('b');

console.log(b.public);
fs.readFile(srcPath, 'utf-8', function (err, src) {
    var box = {};
    var res = vm.runInNewContext(src, box, srcPath);
    console.log(box.private);
});
```

But `vm` doesn't run `b` as a module, so `require()` etc. aren't accessible from the context of the `vm`. So there are `ReferenceError`s like:

```
    var res = vm.runInNewContext(src, box, scPath);
                 ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <module b>
    at <module a>
    at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

### My Question

Which is the cleanest way to **get the value of a local variable declared in another module**? Ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Export getters / setters? You surely don't want others to freely mess with all of your local variables, do you?

Comment: Edit b to export the data you want access to. Don't try to hack into it from the outside.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. But module `b` was written by a stranger and not by me (and I don't want to get my hands dirty). - Any other ideas?

Comment: @fridojet, did you manage to discover a solution?

Comment: One of the best questions i have saw on stackoverflow.
This should be a node module.
 +1

Answer (score 5):

you should probably mostly never have to do this, but there might be reasons.

you can hook the loader and inject javascript code to export what you want.

```
// let's say you have node_modules/foreignmodule/index.js
// and in that script there is a local (not-exported) function foreignfunction().

var path = require('path');
_oldLoader = require.extensions['.js'];
require.extensions['.js'] = function(mod, filename) {
    if (filename == path.resolve(path.dirname(module.filename), 'node_modules/foreignmodule/index.js')) {
        var content = require('fs').readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
        content += "module.exports.foreignfunction=foreignfunction;\n";
        mod._compile(content, filename);
    } else {
        _oldLoader(mod, filename);
    }
};

require('foreignmodule').foreignfunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my module [import-locals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-locals)

```
const patcher = new Patcher();
patcher.export("yourmodule", "Foo");
const { Foo } = require("yourmodule");
```

Answer (score -2):

Just [`export`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) the values properly

Module B

```
// b.js

// some local var
var foo = 'Bar';

exports.Foo = foo;
exports.Hello = 'World';
```

Module A

```
// a .js
b = require('./b');
console.log(b.Foo); //=> 'Bar'
console.log(b.Hello); // => 'World'
```

---

Read more about [nodejs module.exports](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) here

Comment: **`I'm writing a node module called a, which require()s a module b (written by a stranger).`** - That means: `b` isn't written by me (and I don't want to get my hands dirty).

Comment: It'd be nice if all strangers wrote their modules properly. But that isn't the case. Sometimes, you need to help them export the things they should've done.